# Pick randomly user from list to another list

Tags: java, list, random

I'm trying to pick users randomly from this list:

```
private static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

into this one:

```
private static List<Lunchpairs> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is my code:

```
public static List<Lunchpairs> getPairs() throws NoUserException{

    if(users.isEmpty()){
        throw new NoUserException("No participants.");
    }

    for(int i=0; i< 2; i++){

        Random pickPairs = new Random();
        Lunchpairs randomPairs = users.get(pickPairs.nextInt(users.size()));
        pairs.add(randomPairs);

    }
    return pairs;

}
```

But it doesn't work like this. I think the problem is that I can't get the names from `List<User>` and get it into `List<Lunchpairs>`. (If i'm not right, please let me know)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: We might need to see the `User` and `Launchpairs` class to be able to help you. At the moment it looks like you're trying to assign a `User` object to a `Launchpairs` object.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work like this?"

Comment: Eclipse tells me:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from User to Lunchpairs

Comment: What is the relation between `Lunchpairs` and `User` ?

Comment: 'User' contains users with firstname, surname, mail, department. I'm trying to pick two users from 'List<User>' and get them into 'List<Lunchpairs>'. The Lunchpairs class has a 'user1' and a 'user2' with getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Lunchpairs` has a constructor, that takes both user, then this should do what you want:

```
public static List<Lunchpairs> getPairs() throws NoUserException{

    if(users.isEmpty()){
        throw new NoUserException("No participants.");
    }

    List<User> shuffeledUsers = new ArrayList<>(users);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffeledUsers);

    for(int i=0; i < shuffeledUsers.size() / 2; i++){
        User user1 = shuffeledUsers.get(i * 2);
        User user2 = shuffeledUsers.get(i * 2 + 1);
        Lunchpairs randomPair = new Lunchpairs(user1, user2);
        pairs.add(randomPair);

    }
    return pairs;
}
```

For an odd number of users, the last one gets no lunch at all. You have to to add this to the code above.